# HttpHostx64.exe has stopped working in VS2015

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio

While working with Visual Studio 2015 I am getting  "Microsoft.VsHub.Serever.HttpHost64.exe has stopped working" alert box 
Alert boxes are  continuously coming when visual studio is open.

Comment: Have you "Webcompanion" by Lavasoft installed on your machine? Check by going to Control Panel --> Programs and Features.

Answer (score 2):

That's a bug in VS reported [here](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/1293295/httphostx64-exe-has-stopped-working). You can find the workaround [here](http://thomas-barthelemy.github.io/2015/05/01/visual-studio-vshub/).

Comment: That workaround did not solve the issue for me.  This appears to be a significant issue with Windows 10 and Visual Studio 2015, and, frankly is inexcusable to have been released.  Like Windows 8, I fear the solution is to roll back to Windows 7.